# How to divide variable by 10

Tags: bash

In bash I'm trying to divide a variable by 10.
If I do this it works:

```
  echo "scale=1; 125/10" | bc
  12.5
```

I'm now trying to do the same with variable in a script, so $RX = 125

```
echo "scale=1; $((Rx/10))" | bc
```

But the value I get out now is 12, not 12.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$(( ... ))` is arithmetic expansion syntax being interpreted by Bash, and Bash  doesn't have floating point or rational arithmetic.

What you probably want is:

```
echo "scale=1; $RX/10" | bc
```

That is, "interpolate" the value of `RX` in order to build an expression which is then evaluated by `bc`.

Case is important; `Rx` and `RX` are not the same symbol in Bash.